# Invalid Sender in web3dart

Tags: dart, web3dart

I use **web3dart** and when I send a transaction I get such error:

> error: {code: -32000, message: invalid sender}};

I changed the **chainId**, but it did not help, can someone come across this?
despite this mistake I can get a balance.

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/simolus3/web3dart/issues/28

Answer (score 0):

@Vladimir, I think in your project security settings, there configured "**Required project secret for all requests**"

If that is true then you need to pass your **project-secret** with **:** in your RPC request url like below

> https://:YOUR-PROJECT-SECRET@.infura.io/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID

Answer (score -1):

```
fetchChainIdFromNetworkId: true
```